# Can I implement SQL Server 2012 LocalDB in VS2010 Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, localdb

I looked online and I couldn't find a direct answer to this question.

SQL Server 2012 Express has a new feature `[LocalDB]`. After I installed it I couldn't see any new items in C# Express 2010 (add new item dialog).

I would like to implement this in my application. Can someone please tell me how I can create a `LocalDB` instance in my C# 2010 Express or can it not be done?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing LocalDB version of SQL Server 2012 Express will not light-up any new features in Visual C# 2010 Express. You can however use LocalDB in your applications developed in C# 2010. See this blog post for start: [Using LocalDB in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/11/28/using-localdb-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).